# How to understand which one is unnecessary on BootUp

Tags: boot

I looked every question about this but answers like: "You can find out which takes too long with `systemd-analyze blame`, my output is like this:

```
    1min 25.046s nmbd.service
     20.225s dev-sda2.device
     19.760s keyboard-setup.service
     16.088s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      7.016s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.531s mysql.service
      5.139s apt-daily.service
      4.014s apparmor.service
      3.895s vboxdrv.service
      3.865s fwupd.service
      3.861s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      3.799s click-system-hooks.service
      3.724s ModemManager.service
      3.602s smbd.service
      3.306s grub-common.service
      3.008s plymouth-start.service
      2.764s accounts-daemon.service
      2.469s upower.service
      2.280s plymouth-read-write.service
      2.141s polkit.service
      2.004s irqbalance.service
      1.962s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.478s repowerd.service
      1.429s systemd-logind.service
      1.405s gpu-manager.service
      1.404s tor.service
      1.404s pppd-dns.service
      1.072s snapd.autoimport.service
       856ms thermald.service
       853ms avahi-daemon.service
       811ms udisks2.service
       746ms ssh.service
       621ms apt-daily-upgrade.service
       616ms apport.service
       569ms NetworkManager.service
       562ms speech-dispatcher.service
       550ms rsyslog.service
       547ms switcheroo-control.service
       533ms user@1000.service
       488ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B221\x2dEEC6.service
       482ms gdomap.service
       477ms systemd-sysctl.service
       434ms lm-sensors.service
       428ms systemd-journald.service
       426ms systemd-rfkill.service
       415ms ufw.service
       365ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       363ms binfmt-support.service
       297ms colord.service
       279ms systemd-resolved.service
       264ms wpa_supplicant.service
       257ms snapd.refresh.service
       216ms boot-efi.mount
       213ms dev-hugepages.mount
       212ms dev-mqueue.mount
       205ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       184ms packagekit.service
       171ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       168ms resolvconf.service
       161ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       159ms networking.service
       122ms tor@default.service
       109ms alsa-restore.service
       102ms lightdm.service
        98ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        86ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        73ms systemd-udevd.service
        60ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        53ms setvtrgb.service
        47ms openvpn.service
        45ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        37ms snap-hello\x2dworld-27.mount
        35ms snap-core-2462.mount
        28ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        26ms ureadahead-stop.service
        12ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        11ms systemd-random-seed.service
         8ms rc-local.service
         7ms dns-clean.service
         6ms minidlna.service
         6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms vboxweb-service.service
         4ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
         4ms console-setup.service
         4ms vboxautostart-service.service
         3ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
         3ms rtkit-daemon.service
         3ms systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service
         3ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
       753us dev-loop0.device
       705us snapd.socket
       687us dev-loop1.device
```

And I don't know which one should I deactivate. Then I write `sudo systemctl list-dependencies nmbd.service --reverse`, but still, It's too complicated for me to understand this chart:

```
    nmbd.service
● └─multi-user.target
●   ├─failsafe-graphical.target
●   └─graphical.target
```

My bootup time increased with new system update but before then, I have dual boot and I deleted Windows on my computer. The dual-boot screen had appeared still and I change timeout=10 to timeout=0 from boot config. Maybe that's something relevant. Thanks for your helps :) `systemd-analyze critical-chain` results:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 3.976s
└─multi-user.target @2min 3.976s
  └─nmbd.service @1min 43.949s +20.026s
    └─network-online.target @1min 43.947s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 37.155s +6.792s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 35.485s +1.668s
          └─dbus.service @1min 34.525s
            └─basic.target @1min 34.183s
              └─sockets.target @1min 34.183s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 34.155s +27ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 34.132s
                    └─apparmor.service @24.743s +8.335s
                      └─local-fs.target @24.742s
                        └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @2min 515ms
                          └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 58.528s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @23.532s
                              └─keyboard-setup.service @4.126s +19.405s
                                └─system.slice @4.030s
                                  └─-.slice @3.372s
```

This svg file from http://svgshare.com/i/2ae.svg from `systemd-analyze plot`

Comment: The last one (nmbd.service) is samba and takes over a minute. That could be an external windows disk that is slow to mount? Oh and we need the results from  `systemd-analyze critical-chain` ;-)

Comment: Answer for this might also benefit: https://askubuntu.com/questions/815894/very-long-boot-time-due-to-systemd-tmpfiles-clean-service

Comment: I edited my post and added the command's result.